# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException unsolved

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to add the javax.mail jar to my classpath but I get this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/mail/MessagingException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2663)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2012)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.
```

I've readed in other post that it could be fixed adding the dependecy to the pom.xml, so I did it:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: project]

But still I'm getting the error ..can someone help me with this?

Comment: Try to clear the project and rebuild it.

Comment: @Jens done! but still get the same error .

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Also with the 1.4.3 version there is no longer an artifact id called mail. If you want to use 1.4.3 you should use this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>mailapi</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: When do you get this error? If you are running the code using tomcat, you should check if the mail jar is accessible by tomcat - i.e it should either be in the war\WEB-INF\lib or in shared\lib folder.

Comment: I get the error when the server is starting up @vanval

Comment: Then it looks like your server cannot find the mail jar. If your server is tomcat, after your war has been exploded by tomcat under webapps put it in this location: webapps\<your exploded war folder>\WEB-INF\lib and check if the error repeats.

Comment: "Back compatibility" they said

Answer (score 2):

the `javax/mail/MessagingException` already exists in version 1.4. So I guess this is just an assembly issue within the IDE. Refreshing the pom dependencies and checking the artifact the IDE builds up should be sufficient.

Comment: already mentioned by other users - the class cannot be found because it might not be assembled by your IDE. Try to check the artifact your IDE builds. Also try to clean, rebuild, undeploy and deploy the application etc.

Answer (score 2):

You should add the jar to the server Tomcat.

1. Open launch configuration

   [image: You should open launch configuration]
2. Add external jar (look for your email jar)

   [image: Add external jar and look for your email jar]

Answer (score 0):

The most recent version of the Java Mail API is

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.mail-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Do you get the same error with this version?

Answer (score 0):

This class has been present in all versions of Javamail I have ever used. Clearly you don't have the Javamail JAR(s) on your CLASSPATH, as for any other ClassNotFoundException.

Comment: I don't use that IDE so I can't comment, but my answer remains. The exception proves it.

Answer (score 0):

You mixed the classpath by using maven and manually added references in eclipse.

Disable the "maven nature" make a `mvn eclipse:clean` on commandline refresh your project and `convert it to maven project` and then try again.

To clearify: Where have you added the mail api in pom? under `<dependecies>` or under `<dependecyManagement`?

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing a similar error. Try below 2 steps (the first of which has been recommended here already) - 
 1. Add the dependency to your `pom.xml`

```
         <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.3</version>
        </dependency>
```

2. If that doesn't work, manually place the `jar` file in your `.m2\repository\javax\<folder>\<version>\` directory.

Answer (score 0):

You will use `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy project dependencies to somewhere else.

Add this to pom.xml

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <mainClass>com.mkyong.core.App</mainClass>
        <classpathPrefix>dependency-jars/</classpathPrefix>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>copy-dependencies</id>
        <phase>package</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>
                          ${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/
                    </outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Following manifest file will be generated. The project dependencies will be copied to {project}/target/dependency-jars/.

```
manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: mkyong
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_35
Class-Path: dependency-jars/log4j-1.2.17.jar
Created-By: Apache Maven
Main-Class: com.mkyong.core.App
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

This worked for me. 
Source: [MKyong.com](https://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-manifest-file-with-maven/)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem with javax.mail.Activator class. Solution was delete from war javax.mail and javax.activation and add it on {tomcat}\lib folder